# Is there really nothing compatible with Android that can parse javascript pages?

Tags: javascript, android, html, parsing

I'm completely stumped. After days and days of searching, I simply cannot find anything that I can use to parse dynamically generated HTML pages.

The requirements:

1. Load an html page, and let javascript fill out contents. Allow html to be viewed.
2. Parse said dynamically generated page, and be allowed to click elements and buttons that will update the content on the page.

All the other similar questions from a few months ago point to the same thing, nothing exists, or is not compatible. I'm surprised that no has come up with a library that accomplishes this.

Is there really nothing that does html parsing with javascript enabled? Anything at all???

I've been using JSOUP up until this point to handle my web scraping, but now that I've finished with those pages, everything else uses javascript, and I can't get anything out of those pages.

I've also read about the Android WebView javascript hacks as well, but its completely tedious, and hasn't worked in many of my scenarios, especially when you have to log in, and navigate to a different page. HtmlUnit, which is perfect for absolutely everything I need, is not compatible with android. Selenium looks good too, but you need to install another apk and it seems it can only be used for testing.

Has anything new been developed, or is in development? Anyone have any insight? Is there any possible way to go about this? Does a proper library/way not exist???

Comment: one question... why do you need to parse javascript generated page? I'd say the WebView is your best bet. Enable javascript, load the page and done.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix - it appears the goal is to scrape pages off a server, rather than to generate a local html+javascript user experience (which tends to work fine).  It is true that a lot of the web these days is unfortunately not static html...

Comment: @ChrisStratton scraping websites from an android device? If the page is generated using javascript there might be an API which would make more sense to use instead of parsing content.

Comment: Sure, there might be.  And then there might not.  I see no reason why a mobile device (vs. a fixed one) can't be used for light-duty scraping.  A particular application might be a web site that excludes critical information from it's mobile version, while having a desktop version that is hard to navigate on a mobile screen.

Comment: My goal is to create a native app for my University. Basic features would have been checking grades and assignments and others. The website doesn't have a mobile friendly version, and often has problems working in the Android browser. And of course, all of the content is dynamically generated after page load.

Comment: The browser already knows how to parse HTML and execute javascript.  Since you want to create a native app, is there any reason why you can't create e.g. a webview instance hidden behind another element, allow it to run and render the page using javascript, and then run your own javascript directly on the page to look directly at the DOM to build your own new, simplified page?

Comment: I've looked into the the webview as well. All the examples lead to injecting javascript on the onPageFinished event. But after all that, say after a user selects a option, or clicks a button, how do I inject more javascript to navigate to a new page, or get new content?

Answer (score 1):

I think the right solution could be [bobik](https://www.webcrawling.net) it's seems works so far.
Bobik is a cloud-powered service for scraping websites in real time. You can use any language you want as Bobik's own API is entirely HTTP-based. Jobs are processed immediately after the submission and results are ready within seconds.